# Programmatic Event Trigger using Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, html, hammer.js

I am finding it very difficult to create programmatic events using Hammer.js.  What I would like is to have two elements, when element one is tapped, I would like to fire or trigger or emit an event on the second element as well.

My end goal is to use this technique when dragging items.  Basically, hold down on an element to create a clone of it, and then emit the drag event on the clone.  This would stop dragging the original element and start the drag on the new cloned element.

With that said, I've created a simple jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vk3reu0w/1/.  It has two div elements.  What I am trying to do is have div one be tapped and an event automatically fire a tap event on div two.

```
var buttonOne = document.getElementById("one");
var buttonTwo = document.getElementById("two");

var mc1 = Hammer(buttonOne);
var mc2 = Hammer(buttonTwo);

mc1.on("tap", function(event) {
    alert("MC1 Tapped");
    console.log("MC1 Tapped");          
    mc2.emit("tap");            
});

mc2.on("tap", function(event) {
    alert("MC2 Tapped");
    console.log("MC2 Tapped");          
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to **.emit** method a second param.

```
 mc1.on("tap", function(event) {
    alert("MC1 Tapped");
    console.log("MC1 Tapped");          
    mc2.emit("tap", event); // HERE           
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvgcupg/1/

You can custom your event as well.

```
mc1.on("tap", function(event) {
    console.log("MC1 Tapped");          
    var customEvent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event)); // Creating
    customEvent.center.x = 999; // ...changing something
    mc2.emit("tap", customEvent); // Emitting       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ntgrdq7n/3/